# JQuery Is not Responding Dynamic HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to fetch data from API and Formatting The JSON to display Into the Jquery Accordion. But JQuery Is not responding when I am doing this. ie. the CSS & Accordion Functionality both are not working

**Attempt:**

When hardcoding the JSON data into the accordion it is working perfectly.

**JSON Data:**

```
{
"tabs": [{
    "tab_elements": [{
        "details": [{
            "element_display_name": "ABC",
            "element_items": [{
                    "item_source_name": "AAA",
                    "item_details": {
                        "0": "AAA",
                        "1": "#233",
                        "2": "qqq"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "item_source_name": "BBB",
                    "item_details": {
                        "0": "D1",
                        "1": "D2",
                        "2": "D3"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "item_source_name": "CCC",
                    "item_details": {
                        "0": "SH 1",
                        "1": "SH 2",
                        "2": "SH 3"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

**Function:**

```
function display_data(name) {

document.getElementById("data2").style.display = "block";
let data = [];
data = details.filter(x => x.element_display_name === name)

data = data[0].element_items
var temp = "";
data.forEach((u) => {
    temp += `<h2 > ${u.item_source_name} </h2>`
    Object.keys(u.item_details).forEach((v) => {
        temp += '<div class="flex-container" style="padding:0 4%; margin-top:3%"><h6 class="big">' +
            v + '</h6>'
        temp += '<p>' + u.item_details[v] + '</p></div>'
    });
});
document.getElementById("jqAccordion3").innerHTML = temp
$('#jqAccordion3').html = temp
$('#jqAccordion3').accordion();
```

}
**EDITED:**

[In The Image You Can see there is a Details Accordion, When I click on that is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN5I2.png)

```
     <div id="jqAccordion1">
          <h5 style="cursor:pointer">Details</h5>
          <div class="float-left">
             <table style="border:none;cursor: pointer;">

                                            <tbody id="data1">

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
```

When I Framing the accordion from JSON Data it's not responding like "DETAILS" One.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQYE9.png)

Comment: I don't see where you're fetching the data. And I suspect you're not awaiting the response from your fetch before you try to work with the data you expect in the response. But you need to show more detail.

Comment: Presume the data is already Fetched and My JSON is ready
Note: JSON is Already There with the Question

Comment: Not a safe assumption. You need to show the code that's NOT working. All you've done is show the code that IS working. I can't help you if you can't show the broken code... or any errors you're seeing in the console, etc.  It's very likely that the problem is in your fetch since you've already attested that the hard-coded JSON works.

Comment: @MARC I Have shared some images. With Description. Can you plz check that?

Comment: Tells me your data are mismapped. I.e., the data you're hard-coding doesn't match what you're actually receiving in your response. I don't think I can help you any further, but good luck.